# Is there a special process for creating a bridged interface on an Oracle VirtualBox VM?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Using different directions found online from start to finish, I have not been able to create a bridge interface on an Ubuntu Linux VM hosted by Oracle VirtualBox.  (I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with no GUI desktop.)

I reboot the server, but I never see the bridge.  The changes that I make to /etc/network/interfaces never seem to take effect.  I use ifconfig commands to make changes to interfaces.  But changing /etc/network/interfaces and rebooting the VM does not help me.  My `sudo brctl show` command never shows a bridge interface.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "a bridged interface". I've seen questions by other people unable to bridge the "virtualbox" network interface on the Linux client VM with some other interfaces, the reason probably being how Virtualbox implements this interface internally. You should be able to create other bridges (not using this particular interface) nevertheless.

Comment: Should I be able to create bridges purely at the OS level of the Linux guest VM?

Comment: Yes, you should. However, apparently you can't add the VirtualBox interface to such a bridge. So to meaningfully create bridges, you'll need to make a few network namespaces or similar on the Linux guest VM, then you can bridge e.g. veth-pairs between those.